# Bootstrap 4.5, Separate Scrollbars, and Make Div Stick to Bottom

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-tocify-js

I'm trying to organize some elements across 3 columns using Bootstrap 4.5.

The center column will have a long body.

The right column with have content (2 divs) that should be either stuck to the top / bottom. I'm having exceeding difficulty getting the bottom element to stick. The element auto-expands, and I want it to auto-expand from the bottom.

I'm using Tocify as my ToC in the top of this right column.

The left column has several divs. The top div is a banner, which I would like stuck there. The rest of the divs are less important. Depending on the size of the viewport, this column may overflow, in which case I'd like an independent scrollbar for this left column. There should be 2 separate, *independent* scroll bars (webpage scroll and left-panel scroll).

Here's a bootstrap loaded fiddle with an example (with a long body to demonstrate the issue): https://jsfiddle.net/x1nhrwtf/5/

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <main class="container py-3">
      <div class="row">

        <aside class="col-md-2">

          <div class="row banner sticky-top bg-white p-3">
            This will be some banner. Should always stick to the top.
          </div>
          <div class="scrollable-area hide-this-on-small-devices">
            <div class="row bg-white p-3">
              This column is <em>not</em> supposed to scroll along with the middle section, <em>unless</em> the elements are overflown (in which case, I want a separate scrollbar).
              <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-white p-3">
              This will have a search bar. Hide this on small devices.
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-white p-3">
              This will have announcements. Hide this on small devices.
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-white p-3">
              This will have BuiltWith. Hide this on small devices.
            </div>
          </div>
        </aside>

        <section class="content col-md-6">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </section>

        <aside class="col-md-4">
          <div class="toc sticky-top bg-white p-3">
            <h3>ToC Section, sticky</h3>
            <hr />
            This is positioned correct, pretty much.
            Should stay at the top, even on small devices.
            This element auto-expands to 60% height.

            This is a Tocify style ToC:

            <div id="toc" class="pl-1"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="comments sticky-bottom bg-white p-3">
            <h3>Comment section</h3>
            <hr />
            This should stick to the bottom of the column (and page).
            This element auto-expands to 40% height.
          </div>

        </aside>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">Here is a footer. It should be stuck across the bottom. Why is it not there?</footer>

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS Attempt:

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.toc {
  max-height: 60%;
}

.comments {
  max-height: 40%;
}

.scrollable-area {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i worked out. There is the container for the three columns, with overflow: hidden and height: 100vh to avoid page scroll. And the three columns with overflow scroll to allow parallel scrolling.

The rest of your requirements are met, i think. The top components of left and right are marked gray and tay on top. The comment stays on bottom of page and column. And the footer is visible.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

.col-md-2 {
  width: 16.6666666667%;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.3333333334%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.center {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: justify;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.sticky-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.scrollable-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.toc {
  height: 60%;
  max-height: 60%;
}

.comments {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col left col-md-2">
    <div class="banner sticky-top">
      This will be some banner. Should always stick to the top.
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable-area hide-this-on-small-devices">
      <div class="row bg-white p-3">
        This column is <em>not</em> supposed to scroll along with the middle section, <em>unless</em> the elements are overflown (in which case, I want a separate scrollbar).
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-white p-3">
        This will have a search bar. Hide this on small devices.
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-white p-3">
        This will have announcements. Hide this on small devices.
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-white p-3">
        This will have BuiltWith. Hide this on small devices.
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col center col-md-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Suscipit tellus
    mauris a diam maecenas. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac. Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Quis
    ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod.<br> Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra.
    Sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc
    mattis enim ut. Quisque non tellus orci ac. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Fermentum leo vel orci porta. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla
    est ullamcorper eget. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Sapien eget mi proin sed
    libero enim sed. Nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus.<br> Mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus
    vel. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. Orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis
    a. Eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla
    facilisi cras fermentum odio. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis. Ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Senectus et netus et malesuada. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis
    eget.<br> Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque. Faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Non curabitur gravida
    arcu ac tortor dignissim. Porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla
    est ullamcorper.<br> Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum. Leo urna molestie at elementum. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan. Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut.
    Vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum
    lacinia.
  </div>
  <div class="col right col-md-4">
    <div class="toc sticky-top bg-white p-3">
      <h3>ToC Section, sticky</h3>
      <hr /> This is positioned correct, pretty much. Should stay at the top, even on small devices. This element auto-expands to 60% height.
    </div>
    <div class="comments sticky-bottom bg-white p-3">
      <h3>Comment section</h3>
      <hr /> This should stick to the bottom of the column (and page). This element auto-expands to 40% height.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">Here is a footer. It should be stuck across the bottom. Why is it not there?</footer>
```

Comment: Actually, `height: 100vh;` is breaking my **ToC**, which is `tocify`. Is there a way to achieve a similar effect without this? Also, this is breaking the scroll on the webpage. I still want to be able to scroll the **center** panel using the outtermost webpage scrollbar.

Comment: @ch-pub The center panel still scrolls with the `height: 100vh` property on the container because of the `overlay: scroll` option on the `class="col"` css attributes and because the container measures the same as the viewport. But as I have not worked with `tocify` never I really do not know what is happening and what is changing. If you want you can provide me with the complete page and i'll check it out.

Comment: @ch-pub, no, unfortunately is not possible to do it without that property. That property  and the others I mentioned on the previous comment are the ones that allow the effect that the whole page is scrolling and not just the center column.

Answer (score 0):

The footer still right there (at the bottom). I think you didn't see it because jsfiddle's console covered it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was due to the jsfiddle footer.